# SAML Authentication in Angular app Using Azure AD

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, saml

I am developing anjular app, I need to enable SAML authentication using Azure AD in angular application.

Comment: Have you completed it? Please answer your question which will help others.

Comment: have u found any solution for this.