# Implement Azure AD authentication using SAML in web app

Tags: python, angular, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I have successfully created Azure AD authentication using MSAL in the angular application, after that I passed the token to Django and validated the token from the azure.

Now I want to implement the SAML2 in Azure AD authentication.

Using this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/saml-toolkit-tutorial, I have created SAML toolkit for Azure AD and got **login url**, **logout url**, **AD Identifier url** and **certificate**. Using this information, I don't know how to implement Azure AD authentication in angular or python.

I have read lot of article, nothing worked.

Comment: please see: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python

Comment: @CarlZhao, I am looking for SAML2 authentication.

Comment: @Shakthifuture please take a look to the [Sustainsys.Saml2 project](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) and [documentation](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/)

Comment: @AlfredoR.-MSFTIdentity, you mentioned library only supports for ASP.Net

Comment: @AlfredoR.-MSFTIdentity  Can this help you? It uses .Net Core WebAPI and AngularSpa for Saml2 authentication, and it also supports Azure ad : https://github.com/hmacat/Saml2WebAPIAndAngularSpaExample

Comment: I checked that not worked, moreover it will be good if language is python or angular

Comment: https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/12/29/azure-ad-saml-federation-application-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this library to implement to SAML authentication using Django.

```
pip install django_saml2_auth
```

this library supports JWT token and uses **Angular** or **any front-end** application with Django

https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth

Answer (score 0):

This toolkit is simply an application used to test access to an Azure AD Enterprise application using SAML.

From the client-side, you need to add a client-side [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) to your code.

On the Azure AD side, you connect this stack to an Enterprise application.

There are comments relating to the ADAL / MSAL libraries. You cannot use these as they rely on OpenID Connect not SAML!

Comment: It would be great if you post a specific answer.

Comment: Your question was "I don't know how to implement Azure AD authentication in angular or python" And you want SAML. The answer as above is to implement a client-side SAML stack.

Answer (score 0):

@Shakthifuture

Have you checked this StackOverflow answer part:
[SAML Authentication in Angular app Using Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649726/saml-authentication-in-angular-app-using-azure-ad)

Comment: Yes, I checked, that not suitable for my requirement. Added my answer, please check.